# What is the difference between different Canon Speedlight transmitter ST-E3 model names?

Tags: canon, wireless-triggers, wireless-flash

Is there any difference between the ST-E3-NR and the ST-E3-RT transmitters? Or are they both the same?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not as far as functionality goes. The only place I can even find a reference to the ST-E3-NR is on web pages based in Germany. Since these are devices that use radio frequency transmissions to communicate with the same compatible flash (the Canon 600EX-RT), the regulations in Germany concerning devices using certain frequencies may be different and necessitate a slightly different version to comply with those requirements. Even the photo for the [ST-E3-NR at amazon.de](http://www.amazon.de/dp/B007H7C86I) is of the ST-E3-RT.

[image]